# White space above the web part

Tags: 2010

I am a complete beginner with Sharepoint, and I have a white space on top of a web part. The picture is attached. Does anyone know how to get rid of this?! Thanks!
[image]

Comment: That isn't out-of-the-box SharePoint so you will probably need to take it up with whoever created or customized the master page or page layout of the site.

Comment: Hi Dave, what do you mean "out of the box"? Also, can I just customize the page layout?

Comment: Customizing either the master page or the layout is not something to be done lightly as it can affect the entire site and it can potentially cause upgrades issues for custom packages.  It is definitely not something you should do as a beginner but it is something that it appears was done by someone at your company.  That is the person you need to ask

Comment: Thanks Dave. Is there a way to identify who that person is? How would he be able to fix it? Also, what's the dfinition of Out of the box?

Comment: "Out of the box" means that it has not been customized in any way.  As to who changed it, well there is but you probably do not have permissions to see it.  In the site settings at the root of the site collection, there is a link called Master Page Gallery.  That will take you to a list view of all of the master pages and page layouts in the site collection and one of the columns will show who modified it last.